# Online Molecular and Cellular Biology Video Lectures?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology

I am looking for video lectures to go through to guide my reading in intro molecular and cellular biology. I've had intro bio and I study evolutionary theory, but my molecule- and cell-level knowledge is weak.

I'm finding it impossible to know where to look in a big book like Alberts, or to read Lodish without a guide, so I really need lectures to help me out. I've tried the MIT OCW assignments and a few other similar sites, but I can't seem to find a course that includes lectures. Does anyone know of any? Ideally they'd follow Watson et al. for molecular and Lodish for cellular, but I can find other textbooks too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MIT's OCW is weak when it comes to biology videos.

UC Berkeley has some good video content for molecular and cell biology.

- See, for example, this playlist:
  http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=59C08AE05E752758
- And explore the main UC Berkeley video lectures website here: http://webcast.berkeley.edu/

UCSD, if I recall correctly, has had some pretty good life science lectures available online to the public, as well.  Possibly also UCLA.

[iTunes U](http://www.apple.com/education/itunes-u/what-is.html) is your friend here. Unfortunately, to really take advantage of it, you *need* to download iTunes -- but it's worth it.  The last time I looked, there was more there than I could possibly watch, and that was 4 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

[MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) provides very interesting material, and not only on biology.

You may be interested in seeing the video lectures from some of the Introductory biology courses, such as [this one](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-014-introductory-biology-spring-2005/video-lectures/), [this one](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-014-introductory-biology-spring-2005/video-lectures/) or [this other one](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/7-013-introductory-biology-spring-2006/video-lectures/).

There is, however, much more, check out the index of the [available material for biology](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/biology/).

Answer (score 7):

These are some of my favorite biology learning resources:

[iBioSeminars](http://www.ibioseminars.org/)

[Academic Earth - Biology](http://academicearth.org/subjects/biology)

Others include: [Khan Academy - Biology](http://www.khanacademy.org/#biology), [HHMI BioInteractive video collections](http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/video/index.html), W[ellcome Trust education resources](http://www.wellcome.ac.uk/Education-resources/index.htm).

Answer (score 6):

This one is not precisely molecular and cell biology, but rather systems biology. It might help you as some kind of introduction, though:

[Systems biology lecture 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z__BHVFP0Lk)

Also, if you are really really new to the subject, you can probably use "Molecular and Cell Biology for Dummies".

Answer (score 3):

While not exclusively cell and molecular biology, I would also like to add the [Journal of Visualized Experiments](http://www.jove.com/). It's like Youtube for experiments. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Journal of Visualized Experiments ([jove.com](http://www.jove.com/)) is excellent but based on experimental protocols.

[ItunesU](https://www.apple.com/apps/itunes-u/) also has great resources. Stay away from youtube - a lot of people there don't know what they are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend two YouTube channels.

- Shomu's Biology. Probably the channel with the most extensive coverage of biology, but the guy explaining it has a very thick accent that is sometimes hard to follow.
- AK Lectures. Its main focus is on metabolism and physiology. I personally find it easy to understand.